# Is there a disadvantage to having large columns in your database?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

My database stores user stats on a variety of questions. There is no table of question types, so instead of using a join table on the question types, I've just stored the user stats for each type of question the user has done in a serialized hash-map in the user table.  Obviously this has led to some decently sized user rows - the serialized stats for my own user is around 950 characters, and I can imagine them easily growing to 5 kb on power users.

I have never read an example of a column this large in any book.  Will performance be greatly hindered by having such large/variable columns in my table?  Should I add in a table for question types, and make the user stats a separate table as well?

I am currently using PostgreSQL, if that's relevant.

Comment: What do you mean by: _"I've just stored the user stats for each type of question the user has done in a serialized hash in the user table."_ Hashing is an irreversible process - you cannot restore the original data just from a hash. Did you actually mean: "byte array that is the result of serialization"?

Comment: I'm talking about a ruby hash - as in a hash table, not a hash function.  Sorry if that was unclear, obviously the point of hash functions is that they're irreversible.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! For anyone who comes into this with my level of knowledge I'll summarize what I learned from everyone's comments:

   (1) large columns mean you have a lot of attributes you can't query (eg I couldn't query for all users with > 50% on a problem type) - a violation of atomiticity.  
   (2) the entire row is loaded into memory when selected, so a lot of overhead when you don't need that column or if you're selecting many users.
   (3) If you don't need to query on the data, and you need most of it when you need any of it, large columns aren't that bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big disadvantage has to do with what happens with a select *.  If you have a specific field list, you are not likely to have a big problem but with select * with a lot of TOASTed columns, you have a lot of extra random disk I/O unless everything fits in memory.  Selecting fewer columns makes things better.

In an object-relational database like PostgreSQL, database normalization poses different tradeoffs than in a purely relational model.  In general it is still a good thing (as I say push the relational model as far as it can comfortably go before doing OR stuff in your db), but it isn't the absolute necessity that you might think of it as being in a purely relational db.   Additionally you can add functions to process that data with regexps, extract elements from JSON, etc, and pull those back into your relational queries.  So for data that cannot comfortably be normalized, big amorphous "docdb" fields are not that big of a problem.

Comment: Just to stress: An OODBMS is *not* in opposition to normalization - at least this level. That is, they may violate some of the stricter normal forms, but they *do not* dictate "globs of data in a single column", which it sounds like this issue is about.

Comment: I didn't say an ORDBMS was not in opposition to normalization.  I said the tradeoffs were different.  For example, there are cases where nested storage/non-1nf designs can be useful in an ORDBMS, but you can't really use them reasonably in a pure RDBMS.  And at this level in fact that is helpful to understand.  When you can store XML docs in your db, for example, and integrate xpath operations into your SQL query, the data organizational choices you have with serialized data are quite different.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question - now that you mention it it deos seem like a disadvantage to have to load all of this data for every user I get from the database.  Fortunately right now I need all of that data every time I select multiple users.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this serialized approach on systems like ProcessMaker, which is a web workflow and BPM app and stores its data in a serialized fashion. It performs quite well, but building reports based on this data is really tricky.

You can (and should) normalize your database, which is OK if your information model doesn´t change so often.

Otherwise, you may want to try non-relational databases like RavenDB, MongoDB, etc.

Comment: +1 just for **You can *(and should)* normalize your database..** (Btw, it's always okay, even with a changing model; it just requires good tooling.)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the predominant queries you need:

- If you need queries that select all (or most) of the columns, then this is the optimal design.
- If, however, you select mostly on a subset of columns, then it might be worth trying to "vertically partition"<sup>1</sup> the table, so you avoid I/O for the "unneeded" columns and increase the cache efficiency.<sup>2</sup>

Of course, all this is under assumption that the serialized data behaves as "black box" from the database perspective. If you need to search or constrain that data in some fashion, then just storing a dummy byte array would violate the principle of [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1NF#Atomicity) and therefore the 1NF, so you'd need to consider normalizing your data...

---

*<sup>1</sup> I.e. move the rarely used columns to a second table, which is in 1:1 relationship to the original table. If you are using BLOBs, similar effect could be achieved by declaring what portion of the BLOB should be kept "in-line" - the remainder of any BLOB that exceeds that limit will be stored to a set of pages separate from the table's "core" pages.*

*<sup>2</sup> DBMSes typically implement caching at the page level, so the wider the rows, the less of them will fit into a single page on disk, and therefore into a single page in cache.*

Comment: Currently I am indeed using most of the columns every time I use them, although not every time I access a user.  This might change as the website gains usage though, so I'll keep the idea of vertical partitioning in mind, even though I believe I'll eventually just want to move the stats into their own table.

Answer (score 1):

You can't search in serialzed arrays.